# Do I need to reveal the source of my income if it itself is a trade secret?

Tags: united-states

This is strictly hypothetical:  Say I've discovered a way to transmute nickel into platinum in an energy efficient way.  I'm now procuring and selling pure platinum in large quantities, generating large profits from seemingly no source.

It's not enough that the method not be revealed, it must remain secret that I'm transmuting the element at all, or else the market value of platinum will plummet.

Could I be compelled to reveal the source of my platinum by the state?  And do my actions amount to fraud or run afoul of other laws, should I take measures to protect and obfuscate the source of my income?  For instance, purchasing a mine without actually using it?  Essentially, can I keep the origin of my platinum a secret, legally?

Comment: Take the fifth. You likely don't have the nuclear reactor operations license, but they have no idea what you are up to unless you tell them.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can be compelled by the government to reveal information: All it takes is a judge agreeing with a plaintiff or prosecutor that it has some relevance to a complaint over which the court has jurisdiction.  If that point arrives and you want to protect that information you only have three choices:

1. Get a legal team good enough to convince the court otherwise.
2. Face the consequences of contempt of court for failing to supply the information requested.
3. Flee to another jurisdiction before #2 happens.

Comment: Note that "the info sought is a trade secret" is valid grounds to try to quash a subpoena, under the FRCP. The court doesn't *have* to quash, but they do have to consider it.